# Cannot reslove the method StylesRes and Android Application Running on emulator not on Real Device

Tags: android

Here is my ContextthemeWrapper.java Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Many Android source files will look this way. Your code will still compile.

Answer (score 1):

[**StringRes**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/StringRes.html) belongs to `support` package so you need to use

```
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
```

instead of

```
import android.annotation.StringRes;
```